# Add subtotals and grand totals in Axapta 2009 report

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, ax

I have a report like this

Classification Item  Qty  Weight (Kg)  Value

---

I want to add subtotal per Classification and grandtotal to both Weight and Value. How?

Answer (score 2):

To add a subtotal for Classification you need to set the `SumAll` property of the corresponding field to *Yes*. However you would need to calculate grand totals of Weight and Value manually, you can display them in a separate `ProgrammableSection` by running `element.execute(...);` from the `fetch()` method.