# filter axapta report based on display method

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, ax

I want to filter axapta report to display only records with QTY !=0 . The field QTY is based on display method . I could acheive this by overriding send method. The problem now is that if the last record in the section has QTY=0, then the subtotal is not displayed.

Comment: Could you show the `send()` code?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate and display subtotals in the same way you've been [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087342/add-subtotals-and-grand-totals-in-axapta-2009-report) to deal with grand totals 4 hours ago - just calculate and display them in a `programmableSection` manually.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to `return false` if you do not call `super()` in the `send()` method.